# Tengo el siguiente codigo en C#, y quiero agregar los objetos de Casa a propietario

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código en C#, y quiero agregar los objetos de Casa a propietario, ¿alguien sabe cómo?.

```
namespace PropiedadCasa
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Casa casa1 = new Casa { IdCasa = 1, Direccion = "Calle E, No 29, Villa España", MetrosCuadrados = 3000 };

        Casa casa2 = new Casa { IdCasa = 2, Direccion = "Calle C, No 23, Villa España", MetrosCuadrados = 500 };

        Propietario persona1 = new Propietario { Nombre = "Samuel", Apelliido = "De Aza" };

        Console.WriteLine($"Propietario: {persona1.Nombre} {persona1.Apelliido} \n Id casas: {casa1.IdCasa} y {casa2.IdCasa} \n Las direcciones: {casa1.Direccion} y {casa2.Direccion} \n Los metros cuadrados: {casa1.MetrosCuadrados}m^2 y {casa2.MetrosCuadrados}m^2 \n la casa más grande es: {CasaMayor()} \n y la menor es: {CasaMenor()}");



    }
}

public class Casa
{
    public int IdCasa { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int MetrosCuadrados { get; set; }

}

public class Propietario : Casa
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apelliido { get; set; }

    int CasaMayor()
    {
        int Grande = Math.Max(casa1.MetrosCuadrados, casa2.MetrosCuadrados);
        return Grande;
    }

    int CasaMenor()
    {
        int Menor = Math.Min(casa1.MetrosCuadrados, casa2.MetrosCuadrados);
        return Menor;
    }

    List<Casa> casas;
    public void addCasa(Casa casa)
    {
        this.casas.Add(casa);

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Cuando haces esto:

```
public class Propietario : Casa
```

Le estas diciendo que tu clase propietario hereda de casa. Pero eso no es lo que vos queres. Vos queres que cada propietario pueda tener muchas casas. Entonces no tenes que heredar de casa.

Aca abajo:

```
List<Casa> casas;
```

Esta lo que vos queres. Y ahi esta bien. Y ahora tu pregunta es como agregar una casa al propietario:

```
public void addCasa(Casa casa)
{
    this.casas.Add(casa);

}
```

Este metodo dentro de la clase propietario lo hace, peroooooo hay un pequeño problema.

Tu clase Propietario no tiene un constructor, por lo tanto la lista de casas es nula, y cuando hagas eso va a tirar un error.

Lo que tenes que hacer es cambiar la linea que tiene la lista de casas a:

```
List<Casa> casas = new List<Casa>();
```

Y despues, para agregar una casa a un propietario, en tu Main solo haces:

```
persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
```

Ah, y como otra nota, tu writeline no hace lo que vos queres, porque no recorre las casas de la persona.

Comment: Solo te faltó indicarle cuál es el constructor de la clase, cómo escribirlo.

Comment: No lo necesita, tiene un constructor por defecto C# @KroneauxSchneider...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, arreglaré eso.

Comment: @NoobProgramer aprende a usar el sitio.. Lee los enlaces que te deje en tu pregunta.